# Is it possible to print the content of a boxlayout directly through a printer in Kivy, Python3?

Tags: python, windows, kivy

I need to print the yellow area directly through a printer using kivy, python3 and its libraries only.

[Please see the example here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTzRF.jpg)

I am using Windows 10 environment and the final product will be used in windows only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to write some code to export something suitable for printing. The simplest method would be to print the png output of taking a screenshot or using `export_to_png`.